# SQL Server 2005 - What is the "Server Name"?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I just finished installing the SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition on Windows 7. Here is the question, when I first load SQL Server Management Studio, what is the server name I have to use?

```
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name:
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Username: Linda-HP\Linda
```

So what server name should I use?

thank you

Comment: You didn't specify a name?  And use for what?  Are you creating an ODBC connection or connection string to your database?  Are you just trying to connect to it?

Comment: I don't remember I specified a name for that. -- thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most likely localhost or . or you computer name works for the server name if you didn't specify the name of the instance during the installation.

Comment: I have tried localhost and the computer name. Neither of them works for me. -- thank you

Answer (score 0):

Server name would be `Linda-HP` or `(local)`

Comment: I have tried Linda-HP and lcoal, neight of them works for me. I didn't install IIS Feature requirement and ASP.net version registration requirement. I don't know whether that causes the problem. --thank you

Comment: @q0987: you need to specify `(local)` (**including** the parenthesis) - not just `local` - for this to work - does that work??

Answer (score 0):

Run `sp_helpserver` to know the instance name.